# How do I transfer game data from one PS Vita SD card to another?

Tags: ps-vita

I have two PS Vita SD cards: both Eight Gigabytes. I want to put all of my music and *Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth2* (including DLC) on the one I don't use. The problem is, I have worked really hard on that game and it's already downloaded on my other SD-the main one. I want the game, and all of its data on my other SD card.

So, is there a way to transfer all of my *Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth2* **game play data and all** onto an SD card ***from*** another one?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to ask this to end up answering it myself, but...

As stated on a PlayStation Community [question](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PS-Vita-Support/How-do-I-transfer-Vita-saved-data-from-one-Memory-Card-to/td-p/15359509) (which was almost identical to what I asked) by Kermit 1970,

"Use the Content Manager to back up your data to either your PC or PS3. Then put your new card in and use the Content Manager to restore your data.

The cards are never registered with your SEN account it is your PSN ID which is. So whichever device your PSN is set up on you can download Wipeout 2048 to that device.

Remember though that you can only have your PSN on two PS3s"